# Ubuntu 14.04, a lot of problems with `JACK` and `qjackctl`

Tags: 14.04, server, sound

i tried all i could look up on the net to come up with nothing that fixed it

here are the things i am seeing and what i am tring to do is used my guitar via usb to a guitar program and i get CANNOT MAKE A JACK CLIENT IS JACKD RUNNING!?

so i looked it up and told me to use `qjackctl` did now this is what i see D-BUS:

```
JACK server could not be started. and Could not connect to JACK server as client.

Overall operation failed.
- Unable to connect to server. from the messages window i get   20:46:28.114 Patchbay deactivated.
20:46:28.116 Statistics reset.
20:46:28.121 ALSA connection change.
20:46:28.133 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
20:46:28.210 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
20:46:28.231 ALSA connection graph change.
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: Starting jack server...
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: Audio device plughw:0 cannot be acquired...
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Fri Jan 16 20:46:28 2015: ERROR: Failed to open server
Fri Jan 16 20:46:29 2015: Saving settings to "/home/april-tyler/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
20:47:26.302 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

I tried all the how 2s on it the `sudo` this the jack whatever start will not start 
its like noting is working

plz help and if you can remote assist would be even better

Comment: not shere how to make it like in the promts sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your user needs to be in the audio group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER
```

Log out and back in for the change to take effect.